# "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo esto en un servicio hecho en Ruby On Rails:

```
@file = File.new doc.path_to_file_prueba(id_fac_elect) || doc.path_to_file, 'w:ISO-8859-1'
...
@file << xml
@file.close
```

Me arroja el error

```
"\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
```

xml es una cadena de texto que contiene una "Ñ", y eso es lo que me genera el error.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué pasa?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, una aclaración. [\xC3](https://www.codetable.net/hex/c3) en realidad es Ã que es pare del encoding `ISO-8859-1`, también conocido como Latin-1.

Ahora, como el error indica, tu problema es la codificación de `xml` que viene en `ASCII-8BIT`.
Como prueba, un ejemplo:

```
irb(main):001:0> @file = File.new 'asdf.txt', 'w:ISO-8859-1'
=> #<File:asdf.txt>
irb(main):002:0> @file << "ñandú".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        6: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        5: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        4: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        3: from (irb):3
        2: from (irb):3:in `<<'
        1: from (irb):3:in `write'
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1)
```

por tanto, lo que deberías hacer es forzar tu variable `xml` a que codifique en `ISO-8859-1` con `xml.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')`:

```
irb(main):004:0> @file << "ñandú".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')
=> #<File:asdf.txt>
irb(main):005:0> @file.close
=> nil
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu respuesta, aunque no me funcionó sí me sirvió para solucionar el problema.

Para poder que funcionara tuve que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Cambiar el encoding del archivo fuente en mi editor a **cp850**. En mi
   caso uso Visual Studio Code.
2. Cambiar el encoding predeterminado del
   archivo fuente en Ruby agregando al inicio del archivo el comentario
   mágico **# encoding: cp850**.
3. Reemplazar el caracter utf "Ñ" a "Ñ"
   cp850: **texto.gsub "\u00D1", "Ñ"**.
4. Forzar el encoding a la cadena de
   la variable xml: 
   **xml.force_encoding("cp850").force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]